# Does Sitecore website performance improve when serving traffic over HTTP2

Tags: performance-optimization

Does migrating Sitecore website from IIS 8.5 to IIS 10.0 for gains of HTTP2(Page Load speeds) make site performing well. Does anybody have done test or have experience of doing so, to share here.

I don't need usual performance tuning dump, did already everything like page\component caching at different levels, use of CDN, JS/CSS bundling & minification, use of Critical CSS, Image Optimization, but not able to reduce server response time from average of 8 seconds to 3-4 seconds on 3G data test. Don't suggest to beef-up/scale number of CD server, already did. Don't suggest anything to do with SQL optimization, already did.

The only way i see is to move on frameworks like AMP or JAM Stack where websites are HTML files embed with JS API calls &  hosted in edge CDNs. Essentially moving away from Sitecore.

Comment: On a side note to HTTP2, you are right to start looking at network issues if you have done all that and still not seeing reductions in response times. You might want to start tracing network connections between servers (like to database or to load balancer) and also checking if there is a proxy or something in place that is somehow throttling transfers. If there is something in the way in your network, no amount of tuning will help.

One way to test is to try to deploy the same solution outside your current network and see what the response times look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of HTTP/2 is not specific to Sitecore. In fact, you could take advantage of this even for a static html site.

You may find that [browsers supporting HTTP/2](https://caniuse.com/#search=http2) will only do so over TLS, so be sure that is in place. There was an [article posted by Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/i-wanna-go-fast-https-massive-speed-advantage/) on using HTTPS which gave a good example on how you see requests for assets download in parallel.

You should see a performance improvement, but results will vary for many reasons.

This is from his article:

[image: enter link description here]